# Problem with removing vowel from word, it gives correct results only when the vowel is mentioned once in string

Tags: python

I am writing a program that would delete a letter from string if it is a vowel but does not delete if it is the last letter of the word.

```
a = 'hello world' # String
b = list(a) # Converted into List
count = 0
for letter in b:
    if b[count] in ['a','e','i','o','u'] and b[count+1]!=' ':
       b.remove(b[count])
    count += 1
a = "".join(b) #Converted list back to string
print(a)
```

This gives output "hll world"
But when i change the string replacing second 'o':

```
a = 'hello wurld'
b = list(a)
count = 0
for letter in b:
    if b[count] in ['a','e','i','o','u'] and b[count+1]!=' ':
            b.remove(b[count])
    count += 1
a = "".join(b)
print(a)
```

it gives correct output "hllo wrld"

Comment: Don't modify the string or list you iterate over. Copy all characters you want to keep to a new string instead.

Comment: Also, `count+1` could go out of bounds of the list or string, and give you an exception. Instead of iterating the elements, iterate using indexes.

Comment: Why not use `str.replace()`?